# Capture String content information that appears with different format

Tags: java

I am receiving XML tag Content in three different formats.

Format -1:

```
<description> START_TIME: 1400 HOURS     FINISH_TIME: 1000 HOURS</description>
```

Format -2:

```
<description> START-TIME: 1400 HOURS     FINISH-TIME: 1100 HOURS</description>
```

Format -3:

```
<description>-STARTTIME:  1400    FINISHTIME:  1100</description>
```

After reading the XML tag value

1. what is the best way to check presence of FINISH and Start Time. Best way in the sense in the perspective of Clean Code review.

Below code checks the presence of content but I believe this can be write in better way than this.

```
 String description= getNodeValue(node, ".");
 if (description.contains("-STARTTIME:") && description.contains("FINISHTIME:") || description.contains("START-TIME:") && description.contains("FINISH-TIME:") || description.contains("-STARTTIME:") && description.contains("FINISHTIME:")) {  
     //Found the content
```

tag is repeating tag. Another  tag comes with the value START DATE and FINISH DATE

Comment: I think        `if (description.contains("START") && description.contains("FINISH")`     should work

Comment: Sorry for missing information <descryption> tag is repeating tag. Another tag comes with the value START DATE and FINISH DATE. Thanks

Comment: OK then     `if (description.contains("START") && description.contains("FINISH") && description.contains("TIME")` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `regular-expression` :

```
-?START([^:]+):([0-9 ]+)(HOURS)?\s*FINISH(\1):([0-9 ]+)(HOURS)?
```

see this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gI7sR3/1)

and java code:

```
String[] strs = {
                "START_TIME: 1400 HOURS     FINISH_TIME: 1000 HOURS",
                "START-TIME: 1400 HOURS     FINISH-TIME: 1100 HOURS",
                "-STARTTIME:  1400    FINISHTIME:  1100"};

String regex = "-?START([^:]+):([0-9 ]+)(HOURS)?\\s*FINISH(\\1):([0-9 ]+)(HOURS)?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        String start = m.group(2).trim();
        String finish = m.group(5).trim();
        System.out.println("START:" + start + " FINISH:" + finish);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To the start value , I should do a substring on ":" isnt it ?